# React Native - AWS Amplify can't login in release mode android

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify for authentication in my React Native app. I'm having a problem with login, only when using the release mode in Android. Other things like signup, resendSignup, changePassword are working. And when running in debug mode, *all* are working.

Here's my code:

```js
const tmpUser = await Auth.signIn(email, password).catch(async err => {
  if (err.code === 'UserNotConfirmedException') {
    console.log('user not confirmed');
    await Auth.resendSignUp(email).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      navigate('LoginScreen');
    });
    navigate('SignupConfirm', {email, password});
  } else {
    console.log(err);
    Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(err), [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')}], {
      cancelable: true,
    });
  }
});
```

Here's the error I'm getting when logging in:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the "amazon-cognito-identity-js" ?

Comment: yes i added it.

Comment: I finally resolved the issues by adding this

```
"resolutions": {
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1"
  }
```
in package.json